# Ruby/Rails - Sorting and Presenting a Large Amount of associated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I have a model that have a column for name and a column for categories.  There are a large amount of names that I would like to list by category but I haven't figured out how to do it.

Currently in the view I have

```
<% for car in @cars %>
<%= car.name %>
<% end %>
```

which just presents this huge list of that is way too unwieldy.  I'm using @car = Car.find(:all) in the controller to get the selection.

=>  If there a way I can create some form of dynamic table where it groups all the car records by category and makes a new column for each category instance, with a listing of all the associated cars?

=> I'm also afraid that that might be too many columns so after 5 or so columns can I start a new row?

=> Should I do all this in the controller or the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you specify some sample values for the category column?

Depending on what you have stored you may be able to do this:

Car.find(:all).group_by(&:category)

Which will put the cars into an ordered hash indexed by the different category values.

```
<% @car_categories.sort.each do |category, cars| %>
    <h3><%= category %></h3>
    <% for cart in cars %>
       <p><%= interest.name %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Cars => (1999 Chevy, 2000 Chevy, etc)......Categories => (Sedans, SUVs, Trucks)...But what would I put in the view?

Comment: Is there an active record relationship backing the categories? If so what kind of relationship is there between cars and categories? Or is the categories column a comma separated list?

Comment: Car is actually a model with a name field and a category field...so really it would be Name => (1999 Chevy, 2000 Chevy, etc)......Categories => (Sedans, SUVs, Trucks)... so a record would look like [id:1, name:2000 Audi , category: Sedan]

Comment: Ok - the answer I put above should work as long as you don't have multiple categories per car.

Comment: But about displaying the data?

Comment: You can loop over the keys value pairs in the hash, and since the values in the hash will be arrays you can then loop over the Car records for each key. You can put whatever HTML markup you want between the loops to breakup the rows to your liking either by using tables or divs. I know you mentioned breaking them up every 5 records or so - you could use each_with_index to iterate over the array and identify every 5th row. You could also be crafty and use the cycle method under ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper.